# AWS latency issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I am doing some research for work for College with AWS, there is a question where a University is migrating to a cloud solution, the University is in  England, and has a large amount of online students from China and Mexico and they are suffering from Latency issues. what would be a AWS solution to solve this?

would i set up a Availability zone in the Asian pacific Region?

or would i use route 53, create a VPC in the Aisan Pacific zone and put a web Server app Server and database in that VPC?

Comment: Not a lot of information to go on, but check out CloudFront

Answer (score -1):

You should **start by measuring latency** from a few locations to confirm that this is an issue and to identify *what* is being served slowly. For example, is it only certain pages, or is every HTTP request behaving slowly?

A typical cloud architecture is to **host static assets in Amazon S3**. This includes pictures, style sheets, scripts and anything that is served identically for every user. This also takes a load off the web server.

To improve worldwide performance to an application, you can then use **Amazon CloudFront**, which is a content distribution network (CDN). CloudFront can cache content closer to users in over 100 locations worldwide.

CloudFront can be configured to retrieve static content from Amazon S3 and dynamic content from Amazon EC2 / Elastic Load Balancer.

This design is much easier to maintain than putting servers in multiple locations around the world.

See: [Dynamic Whole Site Delivery with Amazon CloudFront | Networking & Content Delivery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamic-whole-site-delivery-with-amazon-cloudfront/)